# Errors During Load .Refer To pathName\frmcustomer.log details

Tags: vb6

while opening `VB 6.0` project in some another computer I am getting this error `Errors During Load .Refer To pathName\frmcustomer.log details` why is it so?
What is missing there ,how it can b resolved?

Comment: Open that log file and find out.

Comment: @raven In log file i see this `Line 144: Class MSDataListLib.DataCombo of control txtParentMaster1Main was not a loaded control class.` can you tell me how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-compile/re-install `MSDataListLib` control and add the compiled control to your project.

Comment: yes I did this but still getting same error, `Line 144: Class MSDataListLib.DataCombo of control txtParentMaster1Main was not a loaded control class.` Please tell me the steps how can I fix It,How to re-compile it , I simply downloded it and copied in my project folder,That is the only way right?

Comment: I don't think copying is enough. You need to register/install the component. I am not familiar with that component, see if you can find an installation guide for it.

Comment: Yes I have seen Installation guide ,there i found this thing only that copy it in project folder

Comment: Did you add it as a reference?

Comment: I have added it my project folder and than ,in menu -> project -> Ad component I checked Datalist option and ,clicked save . but still not working , my OS is Windows 7

Comment: Try adding to references Project>References and add the DLL

Comment: Which dll should I add for this Their are so many dll's in Reference

Comment: the one responsible for `MSDataListLib.DataCombo` control. You said you moved it to project folder, I assumed you moved the DLL(s).

Comment: I moved `MSDATLST.ocx` file responsible for `MSDataListLib.DataCombo` control and not dll(s).